# Function that gives nontrivial limit of $\frac{\exp\left\{ f(x) \right\} }{\sqrt{x} f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for a function $f(x): \Re_{>0} \to \Re_{>0}$ that is monotonically increasing such that
\begin{equation} \tag{1} \label{lim} 
\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{\exp\left\{ f(x) \right\} }{\sqrt{x} f(x)} = C \,, \end{equation}
for some finite, nonzero $C$.

It is easily checked that,
$$ \tag{2} \label{cases} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\exp\left\{ \beta \log(x)^\alpha \right\} }{\sqrt{x} \beta \log(x)^\alpha} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } \alpha < 1 \text{or } \alpha =1 \text{ and } \beta \leq 1/2,  \\ 
\infty & \text{if } \alpha > 1. \end{cases} $$

Hence, my sharpest result so far is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x)$.

The question is whether a function that produces a nontrivial limit exists and how it looks like.

Alternatively, I would also be very happy with any rate optimal function $f(x)$ such that for any other function $g(x)$ for which the limit in \eqref{lim} is zero, it also holds that $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = c \,. $$  for some $c\geq 0$.

Comment: You have $\alpha=1$.  Narrow it down further.  Try $\beta\log(x)$, then a further adjustment.

Comment: I don't think a closed form expression for such a function exists. You can find an $f_1(x)$ such that $exp(f_1(x))/\sqrt{x}$ converges to 1. Then find an $f_2(x)$ such that $exp(f_1(x)*f_2(x))/(\sqrt{x}*f_1(x))$ converges to 1. You can continue building a sequence but it doesn't have a closed form expression.

Comment: @quarague with this recursion I would get something of the form $\exp(f(x)*f_n(x))/(\sqrt{x} *f(x))$, $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(x)$ whereas I want something of the form $\exp(f(x))/(\sqrt{x}*f(x))$. If your recursion does not converge, these are not the same thing, or am I missing something?

Comment: With $\alpha=1$, what is the edge value of $\beta$?  Hint, what is $\exp(2\log(x))$?

Comment: @Empy2, thanks for hints I edited the question accordingly. Any ideas if this is rate optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the Lambert function.

$$f(x)=\frac12\log( x) +\log\log (x)+c\\
\frac{\exp(f(x))}{\sqrt{x}f(x)}=\frac{\sqrt{x}\log(x)e^c}{\sqrt{x}f(x)}\\\to2e^c$$

Comment: (+1) Nice! Minor criticism: your $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Hm.  $\log\log(x+1)$ will work there

Comment: If you replace $x$ by $x+\mathrm{e}$ inside the logarithms then it is fine as long as $c \ge  - \frac{1}{2}$, i.e., $C \ge \frac{2}{{\sqrt {\rm e} }}.$

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed positive $C$, you can take
$$
f(x) =  - W_{ - 1}\! \left( { - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {C^2x + {\rm e}^2 } }}} \right)
$$
with $W_{-1}$ being one of the branches of the [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). This $f(x)$ increases monotonically for $x>0$ and is positive valued. Then
$$
\frac{{\exp (f(x))}}{{\sqrt x f(x)}} = \frac{{\sqrt {C^2 x + {\rm e}^2 } }}{{\sqrt x }} \to C
$$
as $x\to +\infty$.

**Addendum.** For any fixed $C>0$, the function
$$
f(x) = \log ( \sqrt {C^2x + {\rm e}^2  } ) + \log \log (\sqrt {C^2 x + {\rm e}^2} )
$$
is positive valued and monotonically increasing for $x>0$, and satisfies the limit condition.